# Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® on RedHat Linux with PHP - gives an error when bind parameter with PDO for stored procedures

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, pdo, unixodbc

Without any parameters it will works fine, but when parameters are there, gives the following error -

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 8018 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid parameter 4 (''): Data type 0x23 is a deprecated large object, or LOB, but is marked as output parameter. Deprecated types are not supported as output parameters. Use current large object t (SQLExecute[8018] at /builddir/build/BUILD/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254)**

This runs on 
Centos 6 , ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® - RedHat Linux , unixODBC-2.3.0 , MSSQL Server 2008 R2

Connection string :

```
    $con = new PDO("odbc:dsnName", 'sa','saa');
    $con->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $con->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Sample stored procedure used :

```
    $stmt = $con->prepare( "SET NOCOUNT ON DECLARE  @return_value int

    EXEC    @return_value = [sp_insert_into_t_contact_test]
    @paravalue = ?

    SELECT  'returnV' = @return_value");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $v1 = 5, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $return =$stmt->fetch();
    echo $return['returnV'];
```

Simple stored procedure to return "123"

```
    [dbo].[sp_insert_into_t_contact_test]
       @paravalue varchar(100)
    AS
    return 123
```

Additional information -

odbc.ini file -

```
   [dsnName]
   Driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0
   Description=My Sample ODBC Database Connection
   Trace=Yes
   Server=192.168.2.60
   Port=1433
   Database=NSCDB_3
```

odbcinst.ini

```
  [SQL Server Native Client 11.0]
  Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
  Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0
  Threading=1
  UsageCount=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for this, Microsoft driver has develop for C or C++ application and the PDO parameter binding does not work as expected. If you pass parameters **without using PDO** everything works as expected. Replace with `@paravalue = N'".$v1."'`

Fore example - 
normal parameter binding -  `SQLBindParameter`
PDO parameter binding - `$stmt->bindParam(1, $v1 = 5, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);`

Corrected cod snippet:

```
        $stmt = $con->prepare( "SET NOCOUNT ON DECLARE  @return_value int

        EXEC    @return_value = [sp_insert_into_t_contact_test]
        @paravalue = N'".$v1."'

        SELECT  'returnV' = @return_value");
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $return =$stmt->fetch();
        echo $return['returnV'];
```