# Prepared PDO Statement and MS SQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I finally got my CentOS box talking to our MS SQL box on the network, but now I'm having an issue running a prepared PDO statement to it. The below statement works if I remove the :desc from the end and put in the variable name or the word itself. Does MS SQL not like these sort of statements or am I just missing something?

```
$cn = "AARONS";

$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from CommonNameAddress where CommonName = :desc");
$result->execute(array(':desc' => $cn));
```

---

#### edit

After implementing some error checking, the error returned is:

```
Array (
 [0] => 22001
 [1] => 0
 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation (SQLExecute[0] at /builddir/build/BUILD/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254)
 [3] => 22001
)
```

Comment: check to see if the version of mysql supports that feature, my guess is that it doesn't.

Comment: The MS SQL server is a 2005, but that shouldn't matter should it? Isn't the PHP script doing all the work and then shipping off the SQL Select?

Comment: ow ya you are total right, by bad

Comment: I don't know how PDO works internally, but try renaming the 'desc' placeholder with other variable name and try again...

Comment: I switched it to :name with the same results

Comment: I'm at a loss with this now. I switched over and installed FreeTDS and it appears the driver is functioning correctly and I'm getting all the right returns from the odbcinst commands to check the drivers. Now however, whenever I try to use new driver with the same code as posted above, I get a white screen when using variables. When I switched the execute->array over to a bindParam/Value it returned a normal page, but with no results. 

If this keeps up I may just have to do a normal query instead of a prepared. Whats the best way to sanitize the input to just use normal PHP variables?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up needing a `like` instead of `=` after the `WHERE` part:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from CommonNameAddress where CommonName like :name");

$result->execute(array(':name' => "%$cn%"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check your returns and see if an error occurred?

```
if( ! $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from CommonNameAddress where CommonName = :desc") ) {
  print_r( $pdo->errorInfo() );
} else if( !$result->execute(array(':desc' => $cn)) ) {
  print_r( $result->errorInfo() );
} else {
  //success
}
```

Comment: Hmm, returned me this:
    Array ( [0] => 22001 [1] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation (SQLExecute[0] at /builddir/build/BUILD/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254) [3] => 22001 )

Comment: Pretty sure that that means your data is longer than the field size.

Comment: How could the data be too long? If I replace the PDO variable, it returns just fine.

Comment: It could also be a bug, try adding `$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, TRUE )` immediately after you create the PDO object.

Comment: I'm thinking it could be some weird bug or bad implementation on my part for whatever reason. This coding works with the MySQL PDO stuff I have my other pages, just doesn't like the MS SQL Server
    
    $pdo = new PDO("odbc:NWS","username","password");
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, TRUE );

    $cn = "AARONS";

    $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from CommonNameAddress where CommonName = :name");
    $result->execute(array(':name' => $cn));

Comment: After doing some more Googling, I found a few posts that have this exact same issue. Apparently MS's driver is garbage when you try to pass it PDO variables:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441721/microsoft-odbc-driver-11-for-sql-server-on-redhat-linux-with-php-gives-an-er

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628409/im-getting-string-data-right-truncation-errors-from-php-using-odbc-and-conne


How annoying.....I guess I'll download and figure out FreeTDS as the second link suggests.